# SQL Appending Time Manually

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, time, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that handles load times that I use in other tables. Recently we started handling different Timezones and while we are looking into datetime offsets right now we want to manually set the time portion of a SQL Column that is of format smalldatetime. I've tried the following with a variety of variations:

```
DECLARE @AZTime smalldatetime
SET @AZTime = '2014-04-16 07:00:00.000'

UPDATE DATE_CONTROL
SET StartRangeDate = convert(varchar(8),getdate()-1,20) + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @AZTime, 8),
EndRangeDate = convert(varchar(8),getdate(),20) + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @AZTime, 8)

WHERE Description ='Date Load'
```

But I get the error:

```
Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.
```

For most of the ways I have tried doing this. I believe the smalldatetime can handle the data as I have done dateadd functions to change the hour before, however I need to set the hour manually instead of using the dateadd now. I am doing this on SQL Server 2008R2.

Update:

Changing the varchar to 11 I get the correct format:

```
DECLARE @AZTime smalldatetime
SET @AZTime = '2014-04-16 07:00:00.000'

Select StartRangeDate = Convert(varchar(11),getdate()-1,20) + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @AZTime, 8),
EndRangeDate = convert(varchar(11),getdate(),20) + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @AZTime, 8)
```

Results:

```
StartRangeDate          EndRangeDate
2014-04-15 07:00    2014-04-16 07:00
```

Comment: Did you try your concatenation?, if I do a `select` with the expression for `StartRangeDate` you wrote I get: `2014-04-15 10:5507:00`. Can you see the wrong format in the time part?

Comment: Sorry I had previously had varchar set to 8 but made it 16 when trying some other attempts. I set it back I'll try concatenate now.

Comment: Does it still throws you an error now?

Comment: Yes, and CONCAT is available in '12 not '08 R2 I believe the + is the string concatenation function in '08 R2 from looking it up but maybe you were doing something different?

Comment: I never said that I used `CONCAT` for this, just asked about your concatenation. And yes, `+` is the way you concatenate in SQL Server for versions previous to 2012, and I used your exact query for that

Comment: Lamak, thank you for walking me through the actual problem and helping me understand the issue. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect varchar count was used in the set statement without testing via select.

```
DECLARE @AZTime smalldatetime
SET @AZTime = '2014-04-16 07:00:00.000'

UPDATE DATE_CONTROL
SET StartRangeDate = convert(varchar(11),getdate()-1,20) + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @AZTime, 8),
EndRangeDate = convert(varchar(11),getdate(),20) + CONVERT(CHAR(5), @AZTime, 8)

WHERE Description ='Date Load'
```